# How do you create a regex to find and replace all jsdoc array syntax from [] to Array?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to covert all my jsdoc array syntax from `[]` to `Array`. I using Sublime Text trying to create a find and replace regex to handle the following cases:

```
/**
  * @param {[]}
  * @param {[]|null}
  * @param {null|[]}
  * @param {[someType]}
  * @param {someType|[someType]}
**/
```

So here is what the output should be:

```
/**
  * @param {Array}
  * @param {Array|null}
  * @param {null|Array}
  * @param {Array.<someType>}
  * @param {someType|Array.<someType>}
**/
```

The regex shouldn't interfere with js, for example:

```
const thing1 = [something];
const thing2 = [];
const thing3 = {thang: []};
const thing4 = {thang: [something]};
```

Comment: Have you tried writing code for this yet? If so, please share so we can help. By the way, your example isn't as simple as your English explanation might make it seem. You're also doing `[someType]` => `.<someType>` and possibly other stuff here. This can get complicated--can types be nested?

Comment: Yes but i am having trouble avoiding matching the js. `\[([\w\d|<>\.]+)\]` and replace `Array.<$1>` is what i have so far. As for `[]` is just. a simplified version of that

Comment: Bummer, while editing this question was closed. Use 2 regex s&r: 1. search: `(\@param.*?)\[\]`, replace: `$1Array`. 2. search: `(\@param.*?)\[(\w+)\]`, replace: `$1Array.<$2>`

Comment: Reason for closure: "This question needs to be more focused." Why? IMHO it is focused, and has a clear example of before and after

Comment: After editing the efforts so far and clarifications into the post, it'll be entered into the reopen queue. Again, the spec seems incomplete/vague to me. Are arbitrarily-deep nested arrays possible, e.g. `[[]]`, `[sometype[anothertype]]`? If so, regex is ill-suited to parsing complex structures like this, and the expected output is unclear for these sort of cases (it's easy to imagine others).

Comment: @PeterThoeny thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @ggorlen: IMHO it was well focused, and I believe the nesting is irrelevant in parameter docs. What's the process to re-open?

Comment: @PeterThoeny OP never edited their post to show their attempt or clarify their spec/respond to requests. Comments aren't permanent and don't trigger reopens. If they edit the post it automatically enters the reopen review queue. You can also vote to reopen at [3000 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a RegEx replace for this, for example in Visual Studio Code.

You'll have to look at both cases separately, one case where it's just `[]` and one where it's `[someType]`. You can then reference the capture groups from your regular expression in your replace to retain custom content.

1. The pattern for the `[]` case would be along the lines of `@param(.*?)\[\]` and the replace something like `@param$1Array`
2. The pattern for the `[someType]` part would be along the lines of `@param(.*?)\[(.*?)\]` with the replace being `@param$1Array.$2`

I've tested this successfully for the example you provided, but try it on a spare file first. Generally, the process is always the same: Select all you need in a capture group, then replace the matches in a way that retains the existing content and applies your updates.